# Httpd configuration error "no module name web"

Tags: python, apache, web.py

I plan to change httpd `DocumentRoot` into `/home/webpy`. So I modified the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
DocumentRoot "/home/webpy/"
```

The following, I according to [official document](http://webpy.org/cookbook/mod_wsgi-apache) to configure `httpd.conf`
This is detail:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /web /home/webpy/index.py/
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
Alias /web/static /home/webpy/static/
AddType text/html .py

<Directory /home/webpy>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all    
</Directory>
```

But when I access `http://10.0.3.129/web`, it occures an interal error. I have already installed `web.py`.
This is log detail:

```
[Mon Jan 27 11:53:55 2014] [error] [client 10.0.3.129] mod_wsgi (pid=7046): Target WSGI  script '/home/webpy/index.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon Jan 27 11:53:55 2014] [error] [client 10.0.3.129] mod_wsgi (pid=7046): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/webpy/index.py'.
[Mon Jan 27 11:53:55 2014] [error] [client 10.0.3.129] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Jan 27 11:53:55 2014] [error] [client 10.0.3.129]   File "/home/webpy/index.py", line 3, in <module>
[Mon Jan 27 11:53:55 2014] [error] [client 10.0.3.129]     import web
[Mon Jan 27 11:53:55 2014] [error] [client 10.0.3.129] ImportError: No module named web
```

What's going wrong ?  There is no relation about `python path`. This is index.py:

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys

abspath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(abspath)
os.chdir(abspath)

import web

urls = (
'/','WebpyTest'
)

def my_processor(handler):
result = handler()
return result

class WebpyTest(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.app_root = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        self.templates_root = os.path.join(self.app_root, 'templates') 
        self.render = web.template.render(self.templates_root)

    def GET(self): 
        return None



    def POST(self):
        return None


app = web.application(urls, globals(), autoreload=False)
application = app.wsgifunc()
```

Could someone help me ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: You apparently haven’t installed web.py. Give that a try.

Comment: No. I installed web.py absolutely .

Comment: try running a normal program  in python with import web statement in it and see if an error happens

Comment: Everything goes okay when I import web by running a normal program ...